# How to list music files in the raw folder

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-music-player

I am trying to create a simple Mediaplayer application. It works actually, but I want to do is to show mp3 files on a Textview. I got the list like this way below (I think so). How can I set these filenames to a Textview

```
List<String>ListOfMusic=new ArrayList<String>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Field[]fields=R.raw.class.getFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        ListOfMusic.add(fields[i].getName());               
    }
    initComp();
    textShown.setText(ListOfMusic[0]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the `ListOfMusic` and add the items to the `TextView` (preceding every song name with the "newline" character if you want do display the song names on separate lines).

Something like this:

```
String songs="";
for(String songName: ListOfMusic){
    songs+=songName+"\n";
}
textShown.setText(songs);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String text = "";
for(String s : ListOfMusic) {
text+=s+"\n";
}
textShown.setText(text);
```